# Why is my CSS width not working in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am showing my code first

```
<div class = "buttonsHolder">
    <asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnAdd" Text = "Add New" CssClass = "buttonUserControl" />
    <div class = "horizontalSpace"></div>
    <asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnEdit" Text = "Edit" CssClass = "buttonUserControl" />
    <div class = "horizontalSpace"></div>
    <asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnDelete" Text = "Delete" CssClass = "buttonUserControl" />
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
.buttonsHolder
{
height:25px;
width:465px;
border: solid 1px;
}

.horizontalSpace
{ 
width:20px;
float:left;
}

.buttonUserControl
{
width:105px;
height:24px;
}
```

But the `horizontalSpace` is not working, no matter how much width I have given

One more thing to add, I am not good at HTML CSS. `&nbsp;` can be an option to keep spaces between buttons but what is wrong with my CSS, and how can I fix it without ` ?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the HTML as well?  It's hard to answer your question without seeing the HTML.  Is there a specific browser you're testing it in?

Comment: Your buttons are incredibly wide (425px) is a lot.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an empty div will collapse no matter what the width.  You could probably put a &nbsp; inside each div, but see my answer for another approach that is cleaner.

Comment: my post is edited, so please a look again

Comment: other than changing the buttons class to buttonsHolder, it looks the same.  Is margin-right not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want horizontal space between your buttons, put a margin-right on them instead of putting divs between them.

in your .buttons class put

```
margin-right: 20px;
```

Comment: I have changed my post a bit, please have a look and kindly send me your valuable feed back. I am waiting

Comment: it's late and on second look, you may need to put that in the buttonUserControl instead.  I'm not sure how that will work in the buttons class the way you have it set up but it should be easy enough to try both.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it set up, both of your "horizontal spacers" are being floated *all the way to the left*. So you're most likely adding 40px of extra space at the left and then your inline buttons are not being spaced apart at all.

However, I would recommend **not using a horizontal spacing element**. Instead, add a margin to the left or ride side of each button and depending on if you want to support CSS2 or not, remove the margin on the first or last element.

CSS:

```
.buttons .buttonUserControl
{
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "buttons">
<asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnAdd" Text = "Add New" CssClass = "buttonUserControl" />
<asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnEdit" Text = "Edit" CssClass = "buttonUserControl" />
<asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnDelete" Text = "Delete" CssClass = "buttonUserControl" />
</div>
```

If you don't care about the last element having extra right margin, this will work fine. If you want to remove it, there's two alternatives: 1) To support CSS2, you'll need to add a manual style on the last element to set `margin: 0` on it or 2) To just use CSS3, you can add `.buttons .buttonUserControl:last-of-type { margin: 0 }`.

Comment: @Pankouri: The only thing you seem to have added was the `buttonUserControl` class which would not affect my answer.